# Splunk - Calculate time and doubling it from the user selection

Tags: time, selector, splunk, calculated-field

I have a normal time selector in splunk that I think that everybody know.

[image]

I noticed that in my dashboard it gets used in the following way:

```
<search>
<query>MY QUERY</query>
<earliest>$field1.earliest$</earliest>
<latest>$field1.latest$</latest>
</search>
```

Now, what I want to do is to double the time range selected by the user.

For instance, if the user select 1 week, I want to pick 2 weeks.
Same thing for days, months, hours and any time range .

If the user pick some strange period (es: from 1st January to 21 February ) I want to maintain the closest selection (21 February ) and double the chosen time.

> 1st January to 21 February = 51 days
>
> 51 * 2 = 102
>
> 21 February  - 102 days = 11 November

How can I do this in my code.
I'm also willing to trasform my dashboard in HTML (I think I'll do it anyway later).

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

This works for the *range* aspect of your question (eg choosing 17-20 Jul)

It distinctly *does not* work for the "Presets" or "Relative" options from a time picker

When you select a date range from a time picker, you'll get a pair of Unix epoch times returned

If you subtract `$picker.earliest$` from `$picker.latest$`, multiply by two, and assign the result into a new token (eg `"$evenearlier$"`), you'll get the following inside your dropdown's XML:

```
<change>
    <eval token="evenearlier">($picker.latest$-(($picker.latest$-$picker.earliest$)*2))</eval>
</change>
```

Then, down in your query, do this:

```
<earliest>$evenearlier$</earliest>
<latest>$picker.latest$</latest>
```